# Test views from different modules with espresso

Tags: android, android-studio, mockito, android-espresso, ui-testing

I am currently modularising my app. One of my tests accesses two views which now are in different modules.

**Module1** (contains view **id/feed**)  --->  **Module2** (contains view **id/gallery**)

**Module1** includes **Module2** and tests are within **Module1**.
Android Studio shows no error if I reference **id/gallery** from Module1.
However when running the espresso test from Module1, it never passes as it doesn't find **id/gallery**.
*androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id:id/gallery*.

How can i write an UI test referencing a view from another module?
If it's not possible, does it mean all views that somehow depend on each other for testing purposes must be in the same module?

Comment: Which view ID for the gallery is listed in the `uiautomatorviewer` tool when you run the app normally? (https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing#inspecting-ui)

Comment: Any update on this? I'm facing the same problem.